# OR condition between the populated drop downs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created php with populated drop down from sql like country, state, district, town, cities successfully.

now the problem with after get district drop down i need OR condition between the town and cities can any one help on this.

after district am able to display all towns and cities but need to split the selection towns or cities.

AJAX code is

```
if(isset($_POST["district_id"]) && !empty($_POST["district_id"])){
    //Get all town data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM town WHERE district_id = ".$_POST['district_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY town_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display town list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select town</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['town_id'].'">'.$row['town_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">town not available</option>';
    }
}
```

function declare as below

```
$('#state').on('change',function(){
        var stateID = $(this).val();
        if(stateID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'state_id='+stateID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#district').html(html);
                    $('#town').html('<option value="">Select district first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#district').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
            $('#town').html('<option value="">Select district first</option>'); 

        }
    });
```

html code as below

```
<div id="footer"><select name="district" id="district">
        <option value="">Select state first</option>
    </select></div>
```

Comment: share html and remaining js functions code too;

Comment: remember to strip the data of injections before inserting it into the query since you're using SQLi and not PDO.